# Use form data to update web page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, onsubmit

Before I provide a bunch of code I'd like to first find out if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

I've created a web based version of the dice game called PIG using HTML & JavaScript. The user can change some of the game's settings by clicking on a "Settings" button on the main page. This button brings up a modal window containing an HTML form (). I'd like to use the data that the users enters and submits on this form to update various settings on the game's main page.

I chose to use an HTML5 form because was hoping to use the native HTML5 form validation capabilities rather than try and replicate that validation checking logic myself using JavaScript.

So my approach was to use javascript to get the data off the form on submit. I tried two different approaches to get this to work:

1) Using an "onsubmit=function getSettings()" on the  tag
2) Using a submit button  for the form with an onclick="getSettings()".

With both of these approaches I was able to successfully get all the values from the form on submit and use those values to successfully populate the main game page using the gettSettings() function however when I exit the getSettings() function the webpage values that I updated don't stick...they revert back to the original values regardless of which of these two approaches I use.

I know the values were successfully updated because when I set a break point on the last statement of the getSettings() method I can see that all of the values on the main page have been updated to reflect what was filled in on the form...so I know I'm grabbing all of the data successfully and updating the main page with those values.

I'm puzzled as to why the values that I successfully change on the web page simply revert back to their original value upon exit of the getSettings() function.

**Maybe it's just not possible to do what I'm trying to do?** And if not does anyone know why given I can see the values are successfully changed before they revert back to their original value. What am I missing?

Again I'm using a Form and collecting the data on submit so that I can leverage the "native" HTML5 form validation capabilities.

Regards.

***** EDIT TO ADD KEY SEGMENTS OF CODE *******

Here is the code HTML Code for the modal form:

```
<form name="config-settings" onsubmit="getSettings()">
    <!--                <form name="config-settings">-->
    <span class="errMsg"></span>

    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div>
            <label>Player 1:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="input-name-0" id="input-name-0" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter name" pattern="^\S+$">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div>
            <label>Player 2:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="input-name-1" id="input-name-1" maxlength="6" placeholder="Enter name" pattern="^\S+$">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div>
            <label>Winning Score:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="winning-score" id="winning-score" default="100" placeholder="Enter winning score">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div>
            <label>Number of Dice:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="diceValues" id="dice-value">
              <option value=""> - Select - </option>
              <option value="dice-1">One Dice</option> 
              <option value="dice-2">Two Dice</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--    Below is alt method I used to submit form..yields same results      -->
    <!--    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getSettings()">-->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here are the global variables defined and used in getSettings() method:

```
// Global variables
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, gamePlaying, gamesWonCount, playerNames, winningScore, numOfDice, matchScore, msgs;
var player0, player1, score;
var player0Field = document.getElementById('name-0');
var player1Field = document.getElementById('name-1');
var scoreField = document.getElementById('winScore');
```

Here is the listener for the Settings button on the main web page that brings up the setting modal window containing the settings form:

```
//*********************************************************
// Open Settings Modal Windows 
//*********************************************************
document.querySelector('.btn-settings').addEventListener('click', function () {

    // Settings can't be changed if game is actively underway
    if (!gamePlaying || roundScore === 0) {
        document.querySelector('#modal-settings').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        // Make error message visible
        msgs.style = 'block';
        // Create message to indicate settings successfully updated     
        msgs.textContent = "Settings can't be updated during game";
        msgs.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        fadeOut(msgs);
    }
});
```

Here is the getSettings() javaScript function (note: there are no local variables defined in this function...they are all defined as global values (first few lines of javaScript app).

```
function getSettings() {
    // Alternative call if I want this function to be called via eventListner
    //document.querySelector('.btn-save').addEventListener('click', function () {

    console.log("getSettings method called");

    player0 = document.forms["config-settings"]["input-name-0"].value;
    player1 = document.forms["config-settings"]["input-name-1"].value;
    score = document.forms["config-settings"]["winning-score"].value;

    // Reset msgs so they will be displayed each time
    msgs.style = 'block';

    playerNames[0] = player0;
    player0Field.innerHTML = playerNames[0];

    playerNames[1] = player1;
    player1Field.textContent = playerNames[1];

    // Set Winning score on UI to value on form
    scoreField.textContent = score;

    //  numOfDice = document.getElementById('dice-value').value;

    // Create message to indicate settings successfully updated     
    msgs.textContent = "Successfully updated settings";
    msgs.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
    fadeOut(msgs);
    document.querySelector('#modal-settings').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Nelutu, thanks. In response here are my comments: 
 
1) Regarding relying HTML validation..This is just a toy application and no critical info is being saved or sent so in this case I'm not concerned.

2) getSettings() - just gets the values entered in the form and updates the related values on the main page. 

3) I only used the form submission options to leverage the HTML5 validation..AFAIK I have to submit the form to take advantage of them. 

4) I'm not using any local variables in getSettings() method..they are global to specifically avoid scoping issues.

Cheers

Comment: Nelutu, fyi...before I posted my code I  too was concerned that the problem was scope related so I made all of the local variables in getSettings() method global variables by moving their definition to the beginning of my javaScript file...unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. Maybe there is still some type of scoping issues but if so I've done what I know to do to eliminate this issue...maybe there is something more I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...I finally figured it out! The problem was not a scoping problem but instead and issue with how "onSubmit" works.

The solution involved making two changes:

1) Adding a return statement to the "onsubmit" attribute when calling the  "getSettings()" function;

```
<form name="config-settings" onsubmit="return getSettings()">
```

2) Returning false at the end of the gettSettings();

```
return false;
```

Note: I had previously tried returning true but not false. I was errantly under the impression that returning false value from getSettings() function would disable HTML5 "native" validation and force me to implement all of the error checking myself...which was not what I wanted. It is now my understanding that returning false merely prevents the form from being submitted..but it doesn't disable the HTML5 native validations.

This solution worked perfectly for me because my goal was not to submit the form to the server (as there is no server component here) but merely to use the "native" HTML5 form checking and then update the values on the local web page.

With all of that said I'm still not entirely sure why when I didn't provide the return statement or when I returned true why all of my changes reverted back to their originally value. If anyone can shed some light on why I'd appreciate it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what this **getSettings()** function of yours is supposed to do, but I can try to give you a piece of advice:

1. Some of the form validation capabilities of HTML5 are not entirely supported on all of the used browsers(some users don't fancy to update their browser). Therefore relying on the "native" validation of HTML5 isn't exactly best practice.
2. If you want to manipulate the form values in any way before submitting the form I would rather add a listener to the submit button for click events, prevent any other action, make the checks/ manipulation of the form data and then manually submit the form. Anyways, front-end validation isn't entirely safe, so if you're peddling sensitive data it's mandatory that you'll make checks on serverside(if your app uses a server).

To exemplify what I've explained earlier:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //Stops the form submitting.
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    //Do the checks here.

    //Sends the form.
    document.getelementById("myForm").sumbit();
);
```

3. If you change local variables inside this getSettings() function, the variables will be changed only within the function scope. You might want to read about scope in javascript. (this was just an educated guess).

I hope you find this useful, good luck!